# Conditions for the solution of the ODE $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))$ continuous on $t \in [0, +\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Given the ODE:

\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))
\end{align}

It is known that the solution $x(t)$ is continuously differentiable on a compact interval $t \in [0, t_{1}]$ when $f(x(t))$ is continuous (Nonlinear systems, Khalil).

My question: **are there any additional conditions needing to be added if we want to show that the solution $x(t)$ is continuously differentiable on the infinite interval $t \in [0, +\infty)$?**

My guess is: we need to add the boundedness or the convergence of the solution $x(t)$. But I don't know how to verify/prove it.

I appreciate any help or suggestion!

Comment: How a function $x$ s.t. $\dot x(t)=f(x(t))$ can be only continuous ? It's of course at least $\mathcal C^1$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: The solution is by definition, as has been said, continuously differentiable on its domain. What you can ask is for conditions that the domain extends to $+\infty$. One such general condition is that $f$ is linearly bounded, $\|f(x)\|\le a\|x\|+b$.

Comment: Oh, I understood. So if the solution $x(t)$ exists on $t \in [0, +\infty)$, then $x(t)$ must be continuously differentiable. Thus, we just need to know the existence conditions of the solution $x(t)$ on $t \in [0, +\infty)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @LutzL could you please justify my argument? Assume scalar case, from the suggestion (i.e. $|f(x)| \le a|x| + b$, we have $\dot{x} \le a|x| + b$. By using the comparison lemma (in Khalil's Book), it can be shown that the solution $x(t)$ does not blow up (go to infinity) in finite time, which upgrade the local existence to the global existence of solution. Since the solution $x(t)$ globally exists, the solution $x(t)$ is obviously continuously differentiable on $t \in [0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, that are the main steps of the argument.